# Dynamic Jquery isn't loading from LInks

Tags: jquery, css

I have a code that when you first load it, the CSS from JQuery gets loaded dynamically, but if I got to another page and go back somehow it just doesn't load anymore. I checked the stylesheet links and they are all still there. Not sure why the JQuery would stop dynamically reload when going back to that page.

For example: Index page, pretty page and dummy page Load onto the index page CSS works perfectly fine, gets added dynamically. Go to the pretty page and then back to the index page, CSS is still working dynamically. Going from index page to dummy page and back, the CSS on the index page stops loading dynamically.

Not sure why since this is the only page that keeps affecting the CSS out of the many pages on my site.

the content are being added like

```
if(newCont == 'contIndex.php'){ var ending = 'BeforeEndBody/endIndex.php';
var beginning = 'HeadTag/headIndex.php';

$.get(beginning).then(function(headCont)){//headCont is headtag stuff 
$('head').append(headCont);
}
```

and so on

then the head tag has
    
    
    
    
    `

It has everything it needs to work, it just not dynamically working. I don't want to hard code it in though..

Comment: head tag has <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./core/stylesheets/header.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./core/stylesheets/navmenu.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./core/stylesheets/footer.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./stylesheets/jquery.ui.all.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../core/stylesheets/content.css"/>

Comment: Please edit your question and move the HTML into your original post, since it is relevant to the original post.

Comment: `.then(function(headCont))` is this right?